# Iterate through column in a dataframe and count the number of any given result between two values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I'm looking to iterate through a dataframe column and count the number of results between any two values. For example - if I want to count the results between 1-5 for each result in column A, I may start with the dataframe:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 16 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 22 |

And I'm looking for an output that counts the number of results between two amounts - for instance:

| Column A | Results Between 1-5 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |

I've tried a number of different variations of both trying to break it down into individual steps and using a `for`  or a `for x, result in Column A` variations but I just can't get it to work.

Any guidance or thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this as follows. Select rows with values between 1 and 5 by combining [`df.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) and [`df.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html). Next, perform a [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and benefit from [`pd.NamedAgg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) to have *control over the output column name* (i.e. "Results Between 1-5") as we apply `count`.

```
result = df.loc[df['Column B'].gt(1) & df['Column B'].lt(5)]\
    .groupby('Column A', as_index=False).agg(
        **{"Results Between 1-5": pd.NamedAgg(column='Column B', 
                                              aggfunc='count')
           })

print(result)

  Column A  Results Between 1-5
0        A                    3
1        B                    1
```

N.B. This one liner achieves the same as:

```
result = df.loc[df['Column B'].gt(1) & df['Column B'].lt(5)].groupby('Column A', as_index=False)['Column B'].count()
result.rename(columns={'Column B':'Results Between 1-5'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first filter the dataframe and apply `count`:

```
filtered_df = df[(df['Column B'] < 5) & (df['Column B'] > 1)]
filtered_df.groupby('Column A')['Column B'].count().reset_index().rename(columns={'Column B': 'Results Between 1-5'})
```